# Logged in user registers for an event on behalf of a colleage, unintentionally overwrites their contact record details

Tags: civievent, contacts

We have recently required users to be logged in to access member-only discounts when booking events.

We are finding that some people are logging in and then booking on behalf of a colleague.  They don't book for / attend the event themselves.  They're currently missing the "Not X, or want to register a different person?" link at the top of the booking form.

So they are overwriting their own pre-filled details in the profile.

When they submit the form, eg at:
https://culturalenterprises.org.uk/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&id=288&reset=1

it then updates some details. Most commonly it will update the title, and email, but leave the contact first name and last name unchanged.

Is there any way I can stop CiviCRM from doing this on event registrations?  When I look at the profile settings it is set to update the matching contact when it detects a duplicate, and I'm wondering if that's what is at issue here. (Though obviously I don't want to turn that off!)

I am guessing that this is intended behaviour as CiviCRM assumes the logged in use is providing updated information for themselves?

Thank you

CiviCRM 5.13.4 on Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s the solution to the issue you're facing –
https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-overwrite

Comment: This looks perfect, thank you!